# How to update pivot table records using Eloquent in Laravel

Tags: laravel, pivot-table

Here is the source code of model and controller.

My Role.php

```
class Role extends Model
{
    public function permissions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Permission');
    }
}
```

My Permission.php

```
 class Permission extends Model
    {
        public function roles()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Role');
        }
    }
```

My Controller

```
class RoleController extends Controller
{

    public function update(Request $request, $id) {
          $role = Role::findOrfail($id);
          $roleid = $role->id;
          $permissions = $request->permissions;
          foreach ($role as $roles) {
                 $roles->permissions()->updateExistingPivot($roleid, $permissions);
          }
    }
}
```

i will appreciate your help.Thanks

Comment: why are you trying to iterating a single Role model? you only have one Role what is there to iterate?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to 'sync' the permissions for the role, make this role only have the permissions that have been passed via the Request input:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id) 
{
    // validate the permissions array
    ...

    $role = Role::findOrFail($id);

    $role->permissions()->sync($request->input('permissions', []));

    ...
}
```

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Eloquent - Relationships - Updating Many to Many Relationship - Syncing Associations](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) `sync`

Answer (score 1):

you can use laravel builtin  functions

**Add** = `attach`

**Delete** = `detach`

**Update** = `sync`

more info
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

Answer (score 0):

**Pass Array data while update data**

```
class RoleController extends Controller
{
        public function update(Request $request, $id) {
          $input = $request->all();
          $role = Role::findOrfail($id);
          $roleid = $role->id;
          $permissions = $input['permissions'];
          foreach ($role as $roles) {
                 $roles->permissions()->updateExistingPivot($roleid, $permissions);
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: getting this error      Call to a member function permissions() on boolean

Answer (score 0):

To update records in pivot table, first detach all of the permissions attached to that specific role in update function. Then store all permissions that you get from $request like this:

```
class RoleController extends Controller
    {
        public function update(Request $request, Role $role)
        {
            $role->permissions()->detach();

            foreach ($request->permissions as $permission) {
                $role->permissions()->attach($permission);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a controller with resource and assign the controller to `web.php`

**Your form's action should be as follows and use**

```
    action="{{route('GustPosts.update', $DataEdit->id)}}"
    @csrf
    @method('put')
```

**Form as follows**

```
 <form action="{{route('GustPosts.update', $DataEdit->id)}}" method="post">
            @csrf
            @method('put')
</form>
```

On Your controllers

**Edit Function**

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $data = Post::find($id);
        return view ('gustUpdateForm',['DataEdit'=> $data]);
     }
```

**Update Function**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {

            $objProductsUpdate = Post::find($id);
            $objProductsUpdate -> ProductName = $request -> get('PNameTxt');
            $objProductsUpdate -> ProductModel = $request -> get('PModelTxt');
            $objProductsUpdate -> ProductPrice = $request -> get('PPriceTxt');
            $objProductsUpdate -> OriginalFileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $objProductsUpdate -> FileName = $file->getFilename().'.'.$extension;
            $objProductsUpdate ->save();

            return redirect()->route('products.index'); 
    }
```